# DataMapper - Simple Associations, DataObjects::SyntaxError - any ideas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I set up a really simple relation using DataMapper:

```
class A
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  has n, :b
end

class B
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  belongs_to :a
end
```

I get this error:

```
dm-do-adapter.rb:70:in `execute_non_query': Cannot add a 
    NOT NULL column with default value NULL (DataObjects::SyntaxError)
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Do you know which column is causing that error? Someone is trying to add a new column to a table, that column is `NOT NULL`, and the table already has rows.

Comment: For me it was the foreign key `DataObjects::SyntaxError: Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL (code: 1, sql state: , query: ALTER TABLE "trade_orders" ADD COLUMN "coin_exchange_id" INTEGER NOT NULL...`.  @sannankhalid's answer works for me.

Answer (score 4):

You need to give the a_id(which is a foreign key) while saving the Class B object. if you  want to make this NULL column then add belongs_to :a, :required => false, now your Class B looks like.

```
class B
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  belongs_to :a, :required => false
end
```

then drop the db and rebuild it.